# how to insert table on plugin activation?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i'm trying to create a table on plugin activation.

```
function insert_custom_table(){
   global $wpdb;
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   if (count($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE "wp_custom_plugin"')) == 0){

    $sql_query_to_create_table = "CREATE TABLE `wp_custom_plugin` (
        id int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
        city_name char(128)  NOT NULL,
        lat decimal(9,6)  NOT NULL,
        long decimal(9,6)  NOT NULL,
        country_id int  NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT city_pk PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )"

  
    dbDelta( $sql_query_to_create_table );

   }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'insert_custom_table');
```

you can see my code but I'm getting an error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "dbDelta" in C:\xampp\htdocs\composer\wp-content\plugins\aaqib\wp-aqib.php on line 98
i need your assistance

Comment: You're missing a semicolon `;` after `)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the condition you have written.

for example:

```php
if ($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE "wp_custom_plugin"') !== 'wp_custom_plugin'){
// your code
}
```

Initially, the query gives you null, which is the invalid argument for the `count` function.

and the best practice is to use

```php
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_plugin';
```

please read these documents.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

and also you have some SQL Syntax errors in your code.
you use `long` as a column name, which is also a type for SQL.
also, `IDENTITY` is not valid syntax for MySQL.

you can try this.

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_custom_plugin` (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_name char(128) NOT NULL,
    lat decimal(9,6)  NOT NULL,
    `long` decimal(9,6)  NOT NULL,
    country_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```